# Differential equation with $\sqrt{xy}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$7\sqrt{xy} \frac{dy}{dx}=4, \quad x,y>0$$
How do I solve this equation for $y$

Comment: Can you change the title of the question. This is very misleading. I totally understand that this this is a very tricky question when you have not come across the problem before, but saying "(very difficult)" in the title, when it is not will disappoint. merely stating the equation and that you want to solve is sufficient in most cases. :)

Comment: I'm very sorry about that!

Comment: Is it $7\sqrt{xy}$ or $\sqrt[7]{xy}$? `$7\sqrt{xy}$` or `$\sqrt[7]{xy}$`?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The equation is separable and

$$ \sqrt[7]{xy} = \sqrt[7]{x} \sqrt[7]{y} $$

Answer (score 2):

If an equation is invariant to $x'=\lambda x$ and $y'=\lambda^\beta y$ then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\beta\frac{y}{x}$$ $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\beta(\beta -1)\frac{y}{x^2}$$ $$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=\beta(\beta -1)(\beta -2)\frac{y}{x^3}$$ and so on.  These are Lie Autodiffeomorphisms, and not too many people know about them, but they work dandy for problems like yours. They don't provide complete solutions, just special solutions without integration constants (because they don't require integration to use).

Just apply the group transformation to your ODE:
$$
7\sqrt{\lambda x\lambda^\beta y}\frac{d\lambda^\beta y}{d\lambda x}=4
$$ 
$$
\large\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\beta}{2}+\beta -1}7\sqrt{xy}\frac{dy}{dx}=4
$$
For invariance,
$$
\large\lambda^{\frac{3\beta}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}=1
$$so $\beta=\frac{1}{3}$  Therefore, 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{3x}
$$Make this substitution and do a little algebra, et voila!
$$
\large y=\bigg(\frac{12}{7}\bigg)^\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{1}{3}
$$
Separation of variables provides the general solution:
$$
y=\bigg(\frac{12}{7}x^\frac{1}{2}+C\bigg)^\frac{2}{3}
$$Set $C=0$ and this collapses to the special solution, as expected.
NOTE:  If your original problem was 
$$
(xy)^\frac{1}{7}\frac{dy}{dx}=4
$$this just means $\beta=\frac{3}{4}$ and the special solution is 
$$
y=\bigg(\frac{16}{3}\bigg)^\frac{7}{8}x^\frac{3}{4}
$$Not sure which one you asked, but the principle is the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried separating the differential equation? You should get

$$y^{1/7} \, dy = 4x^{-1/7} \, dx.$$

Now you need to integrate both sides of that equation.

Comment: what do i do after integrating both sides?

Comment: After integrating both sides, solve for $y$ explicitly. What did you get when you integrated both sides?

Comment: (7y^(8/7))/(8)+C= (14x^(6/7))/(3)+C

Comment: Multiply both sides of your equation by $\frac 87$, so that the left side cancels out ($\frac 87 \cdot \frac 78 = 1$), and you get $y^{8/7}$ on the left side by itself. Can you try that step first, and tell me what equation you get at that point?

Comment: y^(8/7)=(122x^(6/7))/21?

Comment: y^3 = ( (12/7) sqrt (x) + c )^2

Comment: For $$y^{8/7}=\frac 1{21}(122x^{6/7}+C)=\frac{122}{21}x^{6/7}+\frac 1{21} C=\frac{122}{21}x^{6/7}+C,$$ you can now raise both sides by a power of $\frac 78$, so that you get $(y^{8/7})^{7/8}=y$. Also, note above that we can say $\frac{122}{21}C=C$ because C is just an arbitrary constant.

Comment: wait so the answer is (y^8/7)^7/8=y?

Comment: I'm saying do this: $$(y^{8/7})^{7/8}=\left(\frac{122}{21}x^{6/7}+C \right)^{7/8}$$ because $$y=(y^{8/7})^{7/8}=\left(\frac{122}{21}x^{6/7}+C \right)^{7/8}$$

Comment: I am very sorry to be bothering you

Comment: No worries, I'm not being bothered; this is a hard DE problem to solve. :)

Comment: Im sorry again, but could this be simplified any further?

Comment: Edit: it's not $\frac{122}{21}$ (which you initially typed and I went along with it) because $\frac{14}3 \cdot \frac 87 =\frac{16}3$. However, the $\frac {14}3$ you said initially is correct (checked it so). After these corrections, we get: $$(y^{8/7})^{7/8}=\left(\frac{16}{3}x^{6/7}+C \right)^{7/8}$$ which means $$y=\left(\frac{16}{3}x^{6/7}+C \right)^{7/8}$$

Comment: This should be our final answer, and I do not think it can be simplified any further. Also, if this has helped you, please either accept this answer or the other one (accept whichever answer helped you the most). You can accept an answer by ticking the gray checkmark.